# Using Analyzer with SpanQuery and PhraseQuery in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

I am supposed to apply proximity search on the data. For this I use `PhraseQuery` and `SpanNearQuery`, but I can't find a way so that they use my custom analyzer (or any other `Analyzer` for that matter, like it is possible in case of `QueryParser`).

Can anyone please guide me on this? And yes, I have queries like this:

> the . knight

The dot (.) means there can be at most 1 word in between the terms "the" and "knight" and can bear results such as "the knight", "the dark knight", etc.

PS: if it is not possible then please tell me, so I don't spend hours on this issue. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

QueryParser has a different syntax, but it can handle [proximity search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches) if the words do not have to be ordered (i.e. in your case, if you also allow "knight" to occur before "the").